# Sencha Touch : how to reference tab bar item from controller?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

My app consist of four pages in a tab bar layout. One page is a search form, and another is a data list of search results. I want to automatically change from the search form page to the list page when the search results are returned from the backend. I can't figure out how to reference the tabbar from the controller in order to call the *setActiveTab* method.

How do I do this?

**The tab bar layout:**

```
Ext.define('cro.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'main',
    requires: [
        ....
    ],
    config: {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

        items: [
            {
                title: 'Search',
                layout: 'vbox',

                items: [
                    {
                        docked: 'top',
                        xtype: 'titlebar',
                        title: 'Search'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'searchview',
                        flex: 1
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                title: 'Results',
                layout: 'vbox',

                items: [
                    {
                        docked: 'top',
                        xtype: 'titlebar',
                        title: 'Results'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'list',
                        store: 'Companies',
                        itemId: 'results',
                        itemTpl: '{company_name}',
                        flex: 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

**The controller:**

```
Ext.define('cro.controller.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        stores: 'cro.store.Companies',

        refs: {
            mainView: 'main',
            searchForm: 'searchview',
            searchButton: '#btnSearch'
        },
        control: {
            'searchButton': {
                tap: 'onSearchBtnTap'
            }
        }
    },

    onSearchBtnTap: function() {
        Ext.getStore('Companies').getProxy().setExtraParams(this.getSearchForm().getValues());
        Ext.getStore('Companies').load();

        //This doesn't work - help!!
        var tab = Ext.getCmp('tabbar');
        tab.setActiveTab('results');
    }
});
```

Comment: You should be able to `setActiveTab()` on the `main` view http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-method-setActiveTab

Comment: Ok, but how can I call that method when the user clicks the search button, and the search results are returned? That logic is handled in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use Ext.getCmp() it is very inefficient since it performs its search globally.

You already have a reference to the main view defined:

```
    refs: {
        mainView: 'main',
        searchForm: 'searchview',
        searchButton: '#btnSearch'
    },
```

so you should be able to reference the main view anywhere within the controller by using the following code:

```
var main = this.getMainView();
```

then you should be able to use that reference to call:

```
main.setActiveItem();
```

Comment: Yes that works, I replaced getCmp() with this.getMainView().setActiveItem(2);